# Чем можно делать ревью кода?

Tags: инспекция-кода, поиск-программ

Подскажите, какие существуют инструменты для проведения ревью-кода? Скажем, открыть файл им и выделять участки и описать, что там не так.

Понятное дело, что можно в ворд копировать куски и писать комментарии, но это не эффективно...

Есть ли какие-нибудь решения для Visual Studiuo?

В идеале, интересуют бесплатные решения, но я бы глянул бы на список платных.

Comment: Не проще было в любимый поиск написать "code review tools" и посмотреть всё там?

Comment: @IgorR. пробовал, но что-то фришного ничего не нашел=(

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [ReviewBoard](https://pypi.org/project/ReviewBoard/) на локальном или удаленном хосте. Демо [вот тут](https://demo.reviewboard.org/r/).